# Sliding Page Transitions on new USA Today beta site

Tags: jquery, html, css-transitions, transition

I was curious if anyone knows how they did the sliding page transitions between the sections on the new USA Today website (http://beta.usatoday.com). Or, does anyone know if there is an easy way to duplicate this?

The only thing I've seen thus far in my searching is something like jQuery Mobile, but that seems a little much to accomplish this effect.

Any help or input is appreciated!

Comment: The way we figure this stuff out is by right clicking, and viewing source. You'll want to track down the id of the element changing, and look through the JS to figure out how it happens.

Answer (score 0):

they are using something like serial scroll jquery plugin, you can see an example here: [serial scroll](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/)